# I tried to send data to a api. On postman it works but it doesn't work with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I tried to send data with to a api on postman it works but it doesn't work with axios.I would like to know how to add headers to my code.

```
var ticket = {
            road: e.state.road,
            amount: e.state.amount,
            day: e.state.day,
            mon: e.state.mon,
            pay:  e.state.pay,
            card:  e.state.card,
            cvc:  e.state.cvc,
            holdername: e.state.holdername,
            phone: e.state.phone,
            pin:  e.state.pin,
            nic: e.state.nic,
            email: e.state.email,

        }
          axios.post('http://localhost:8080/ticket', ticket).then(function(response) {
            e.setState({
              messageFromServer: response.data
            });
          });
```

Comment: had that problem with axios+react native. ended up using default fetch

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

Check the cors policy with your API, Postman doesn't check the cors.

Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors for a NodeJS API